# Can't open USB drives, Windows 10, code 19

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, windows-registry

I am having a bizarre problem with my USB ports on my computer. They aren't working. I have 4 ports, and the only device that works in any of them is my mouse - an older Razer Death Adder 3.5G. If I plug any other device in, Windows plays that nice "connecting" sound, then instantly plays the rude "disconnecting" sound and disconnects. Sometimes it connects/disconnects a few times. Afterwards I go to device manager and, if the device is a external drive I get the error under the `Storage controller` section, and if it was a mouse, I get the same error under the `Human Interface Devices` section.

Error:

> Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration
>   information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)

[image: code19]

I have looked at the registry following the advice given on other questions, but none of the registry keys suggested have `UpperFilters` or `LowerFilters` that were values that should be deleted.
Here are a couple of the keys I checked.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`

Anyone have any suggestions?

---

**Edit:**

I am able to make my devices work, if after they are plugged in and I am shown the yellow exclamation mark, I follow these steps. However, once I unplug/plugin again I have to go through these steps again. Sometimes device manager doesn't find the device automatically and I have to right click and "scan for hardware changes."

- Right click on the device.
- "Update driver".
- "Browse my computer for
  driver software".
- "Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my
  computer".
- Then, in the list of available drivers I can choose the
  appropriate one.

  - For a mouse: "USB Input Device".
  - For a HDD: "USB
    Attached SCSI (UAS) Mass Storage Device".

That works, but if I have to do that every time I plug anything in, it is going to get tiresome.

Comment: I suggest you follow this troubleshooting and update your question accordingly: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-code-19-errors-2623182

Comment: This is a very frustrating problem. In my case, when I deleted the UpperFilters and LowerFilters, Windows wouldnt boot, and we have to restore to a prev. entry point. Was there a officila fix ever. I have a Asus Laptop with this problem

Answer (score 0):

IF all the devices can installed and work properly on other Computer, let's try to reinstall USB hub driver to check the results:

**Uninstalling USB Root Hubs**: Uninstalling USB Root Hubs forces the system to reinstall the root hubs next time the computer is started. Use the following steps to uninstall USB Root Hubs:

1. Disconnect all USB devices connected to the computer except a USB mouse and keyboard (if in use). This includes hubs, thumb drives, printers, and cameras.
2. In Windows, search for and open Device Manager. The Device Manager window opens.
3. Double-click Universal Serial Bus Controllers to expand the list.
4. Right-click the first USB Root Hub in the list, then select Uninstall.
5. Click OK to confirm. Continue uninstalling all USB Root Hubs listed.
6. Close Device Manager and restart the computer, the driver could be reinstalled automatically.

Also, to make sure if there is any corrupted system files related to this issue, run commands below to do the repair:

***SFC /SCANNOW***

Reconnect the USB device that was having problems and test it to see if it works when you connect your devices again.

---

Try to disable USB suspend feature:

1. Select the Start button, type power plan in the Search box, and then select Choose a power plan.
2. Next to your currently selected plan, select Change Plan Settings.
3. Select Change advanced power settings.
4. Select the box to expand USB Settings > USB selective suspend settings.
5. Select Plugged in, select the drop down menu, and then select disabled.
6. If you're using a laptop, select Battery, select the drop down menu, and then select disabled.
7. Select Apply > OK.

Comment: After I follow your steps the devices show up at the bottom, in a list titled "Unknown". I then follow the same steps I listed in the edit to my original question and they work until I unplug them.

Comment: After what you have done, have you tried to unplug and plug in to check the device status?

Comment: As soon as I unplug, plug back in, the computer has forgotten about it and I have to reinstall the driver.

Comment: Try to disable USB suspend, if issue persists, please help to collect C:\Windows\INF\setupapi.dev.log, setupapi.setup.log onto Network drive and share the link here.

Comment: Might also go into Device Manager and ensure View => Hidden Devices is checked so that you can identify and remove any hidden USB devices as well.